# What is wrong with this correct condition? :)

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I find this very strange. As far as I can tell nothing is wrong with this statement, but when running it it always evaluates to false, no matter what number I enter.

```
if(temp>=1 && temp<=5)
```

`temp` is a integer that I only want to be a number between 1-5. So, first half of the statement reads `if(temp is equal to or greater then one AND if temp is less then or equal to 5).` I think this should return true if you enter 3 for example, since this is greater then 1 AND less then 5 but it doesn't. What am I missing? :)

EDIT
complete loop:

```
int temp;
int arrayStorlek=0;
int tempBytesIndex[5];

  for(;;){ 
     temp=getchar();
     if(temp=='n' || temp=='N'){
         printf("Du är nöjd");
         beraknaHand(kortHand);
         }
     else{
       printf("Hära \n%i\n ", temp);
       system("pause");   
       if( isdigit(temp)){
            if(temp<=5 && temp>=1){
                printf("temp är större än 0 och mindre än 5");
                tempBytesIndex[i++] = temp-'0';
                arrayStorlek++;
                }
            else
               printf("du måste ange ett intervall mellan 1-5");   
               }
       else if (temp=='\n' || temp==EOF){ 
            printf("Slut på inlästa filer");
              system("pause");
              break;
              }
       else
          printf("\n Du får bara ange siffror, eller ange N om du är nöjd");
}
```

When printing the variable `temp` it returns a value above 50, even if I enter a 3. How can this be? :)

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Post some example code using this!

Comment: You have a hanging semicolon.

Comment: Try adding printf("%d\n",temp); to see what value it thinks temp is.  One possibility is that temp contains a character "3" instead of the number 3.

Comment: there's no problem: http://ideone.com/roQNf

Comment: When printing the variable `temp` it returns a value above 50, even if I added a 3. How can this be? I entered the whole loop in the main post

Comment: You entered an ascii "3" which has a value of 51, your mixing ascii character and integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/) returns int, but that number represents the code of the character. [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) suits you better, I think, or you must convert char that you get from getchar to int.

Comment: I've declared the variable temp as a int, just above the for-loop so I would be very surprised if it got declared as a char :)

Comment: now I see it, I'm editing the answer, you are using getchar wrong

Comment: Thanks. getChar returned the ascii reprentation, so I edited the condition to if(temp<=53 && temp>=49) and now it works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

The following test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int temp = 3;
    if(temp>=1 && temp<=5) { printf("yes"); }
    else { printf("no"); }
}
```

prints "yes". So… yes, your understanding of the condition is correct and apparently one of your other assumptions is false.